# MonoTouch - Threading

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, threadpool, task-parallel-library

A common task is to do something in the background thread, then when done, pass the results to the UI thread and inform the user.

I understand there are two common ways:

I can use the TPL:

```
var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext ();

Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {
    DoSomeExpensiveTask();
    return "Hi Mom";
}).ContinueWith (t => { 
    DoSomethingInUI(t.Result);             
}, context);
```

Or the Older ThreadPool:

```
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem ((e) => {
          DoSomeExpensiveTask();
      this.InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
             DoSomethingInUI(...);
      });
});
```

Is there a recommended way to go when using MonoTouch to build iOS apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I prefer the syntax of [Task Parallel Library](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx&ei=GU69Tp-KIano0QHI5KXHBA&usg=AFQjCNGjTfP3C9wE1gKSbCEzZlCOZrAYkA) the `ThreadPool` code base is older (in both Mono and MonoTouch) so you're more likely to find documentation for it and less likely to hit a [bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2007).

Comment: Is the ThreadPool code base still the more stable option or are they both equally stable at this point?

Comment: Pretty sure it's quite comparable today... at least I'm not aware of any remaining bug. Right now a lot of testing is being done with Mono 3.0 (Xamarin.iOS 6.3 betas) for the async support.

Answer (score 1):

According to this document, mono touch provides access to ThreadPool and Thread:

> The MonoTouch runtime gives access to developers to the .NET threading
>   APIs, both explicit use of threads (System.Threading.Thread,
>   System.Threading.ThreadPool) as well as implicitly when using the
>   asynchronous delegate patterns or the BeginXXX methods.

http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/threading

Also, you should call InvokeOnMainThread to update your UI.