# Good way to terminate a thread (without Thread.Abort)

Tags: c#, multithreading, terminate, abort

I've read in a bunch of places that I should stay away from Thread.Abort. And learned the hard way that it's true (it seem to have quite platform dependent behavior on Mono) :))

**So what's the good/graceful way to terminate a thread from outside?**

I understand that I can add a code like this:

```
if (terminateRequested) return;
```

or better

```
if (terminateRequested) throw new MyTerminateThreadException();
```

but in real world case where thread code is spread over multiple C# files it quickly becomes an annoying and duplicated pattern.

**And how about situations where thread is Sleeping, waiting for server connection, mutex or executing code which is not mine? How do you deal with those?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632149/question-about-terminating-a-thread-cleanly-in-net/3632642#3632642 - Possibly of help?

Comment: There are just too many different scenarios to answer this question properly in a short amount of space. It really just depends on each specific scenario. That said, barring the use of `Thread.Abort()` (which I agree is an awful way to interrupt a thread), you're pretty much stuck checking some state somewhere if you want an actively-running thread to be interrupted.

Comment: Does Mono have the `Task` class available? If so, you could use a `CancellationToken` to interrupt a thread.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Mono has the `Task` [class available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8097080/478049). I would recommend looking through using `CancellationToken`. Check out this [Task Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page for a better idea of executing a thread and cancelling it.